# Pandas - Read in JSON (and add ID column)

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

Not sure of the best title for this scenario but basically I have a JSON output that I'd like to convert into a pandas df.

The initial JSON looks like:

```
data = [{'Balance': 0.0,
  'Currency': 'USD',
  'Deposit': 0.0,
  'Narration': '',
  'TransactionDate': '2000-01-01T00:00:00Z',
  'TransactionType': 'Opening Balance',
  'ValuePortfolioCurrency': 0.0,
  'Withdrawal': 0.0},
 {'Balance': 15000.0,
  'Currency': 'USD',
  'Deposit': 15000.0,
  'Narration': 'XYZ',
  'TransactionDate': '2010-01-01T00:00:00Z',
  'TransactionType': 'Deposit',
  'ValuePortfolioCurrency': 15000.0,
  'Withdrawal': 0.0},
 {'Balance': 13000.0,
  'Currency': 'USD',
  'Deposit': 0.0,
  'Narration': 'ABC',
  'TransactionDate': '2010-12-01T00:00:00Z',
  'TransactionType': 'Transfer Out',
  'ValuePortfolioCurrency': -2000.0,
  'Withdrawal': -2000.0}]
```

**I can very comfortably get that into a df with simply `pd.DataFrame(data)`.**

df:

```
    Balance Currency    Deposit Narration   TransactionDate     TransactionType     ValuePortfolioCurrency    Withdrawal
0   0.0     USD         0.0               2000-01-01T00:00:00Z  Opening Balance              0.0               0.0
1   15000.0 USD         15000.0  XYZ      2010-01-01T00:00:00Z  Deposit                  15000.0                0.0
2   13000.0 USD         0.0      ABC      2010-12-01T00:00:00Z  Transfer Out            -2000.0              -2000.0
```

However I want to append an ID to the whole transaction block from a different nest of the JSON. Now I have control about how to add that ID.. I can add it to make a list of lists or use a dict with the ID as the key?

This could look like below snippet using `1234` as the ID.

```
data = ['1234',[{'Balance': 0.0,
  'Currency': 'USD',
  'Deposit': 0.0,
  'Narration': '',
  'TransactionDate': '2000-01-01T00:00:00Z',
  'TransactionType': 'Opening Balance',
  'ValuePortfolioCurrency': 0.0,
  'Withdrawal': 0.0}...]]
```

or..

```
data = {'1234':[{'Balance': 0.0,
  'Currency': 'USD',
  'Deposit': 0.0,
  'Narration': '',
  'TransactionDate': '2000-01-01T00:00:00Z',
  'TransactionType': 'Opening Balance',
  'ValuePortfolioCurrency': 0.0,
  'Withdrawal': 0.0}...]}
```

So the final output I would like is to have a column with the ID for all of the inner transactions like below (see last column):

```
    Balance Currency    Deposit Narration   TransactionDate     TransactionType     ValuePortfolioCurrency    Withdrawal      ID
0   0.0     USD         0.0               2000-01-01T00:00:00Z  Opening Balance              0.0               0.0         1234
1   15000.0 USD         15000.0  XYZ      2010-01-01T00:00:00Z  Deposit                  15000.0                0.0           1234
2   13000.0 USD         0.0      ABC      2010-12-01T00:00:00Z  Transfer Out            -2000.0              -2000.0        1234
```

I've tried a few things with `json_normalize` but couldn't get anything to work. Hope this all makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with a dummy `id` list. It works by iterating over the list of dictionaries that you provided and adds a new key called `id`:

```
n = len(data)
ids = ['1234'] * n

for i,j in zip(data, ids):
    i["id"] = j

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

  Balance Currency  Deposit Narration       TransactionDate  TransactionType  \
0      0.0      USD      0.0            2000-01-01T00:00:00Z  Opening Balance   
1  15000.0      USD  15000.0       XYZ  2010-01-01T00:00:00Z          Deposit   
2  13000.0      USD      0.0       ABC  2010-12-01T00:00:00Z     Transfer Out   

   ValuePortfolioCurrency  Withdrawal    id  
0                     0.0         0.0  1234  
1                 15000.0         0.0  1234  
2                 -2000.0     -2000.0  1234
```